# JAR не выполняется на других компьютерах

Tags: java

Первая неделя с Java. Написал программу шифровальщик. Использовал только встроенные возможности. Собрал JARник, на компьютере на котором программировал, всё работает отлично, на других компьютерах не запускается. Выскакивает ошибка:

> ERROR: A JNI error has occurred...

Может я что-то настроил при компиляции не правильно. Подскажите, как исправить?
Работаю с JDK 10.0.1 совместно с IntelliJ IDEA

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: полную ошибку в студию.

Comment: предлагаю два простых варианта: на других компьютерах не установлена jdk или у вас в программе используется абсолютный путь

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев а чтобы пользоваться JAR-программой нужно обязательно JDK? Разве JRE недостаточно?
"или у вас в программе используется абсолютный путь"
использовал только `file.getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: по-идее должно быть достаточно, но я бы проверил =)

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев у меня на рабочем даже JDK не устанавливается, на остальных не пробовал.

Comment: @Tsyklop прикрепил скриншот с ошибкой

Comment: на лицо ошибка "не установлена java машина". Вы в системные переменные добавили путь в java машине?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80292/discussion-between---and--).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь запустить программу на виртуальной машине более старой версии, чем компилятор, которым эта программа компилировалась. Либо обновите JRE компьютера, на котором возникает проблема, либо при компиляции укажите целевую платформу с помощью ключа [-target](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCJDCID).

Comment: Несколько раз переустанавливал JRE. Брал его и с java.com и с oracle. Но не помогает. Наверно проще всего перекомпилировать на минимальной версии платформы. Но на какой версии JDK тогда разрабатывать и компилировать? Чтобы была совместимость с JRE java.com?

Comment: У вас используется JRE 8, а JDK 10. С сайта Oracle легко скачать и [JRE 10](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre10-downloads-4417026.html).

Comment: а где взять JRE для 32х разрядной ОС?

Comment: Oracle JDK существует только для 64-разрядных систем начиная с Java 9. Вам придётся либо использовать более раннюю версию, либо собрать JDK под интересующую платформу самостоятельно, используя исходный код OpenJDK.